# static images not served after deployment to heroku

Tags: python, heroku, assets, plotly-dash

I'm working on a small web application built with python and plotly-dash. Everything worked fine locally and so I deployed the code to Heroku. This also worked fine except for 2 out of 17 static images in the assets folder that won't get served after deployment. The error message is:
*Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)*

The initial settings for plotly-dash were set to 'serve assets locally'. So I tried to serve them from an S3 bucket with the same result. These two images can't be found on the server.
One more piece of information. I saw that the file extension for both of these files was '.JPG' instead of '.jpg' for all the other files that are showed correctly. I saved them under XY.jpg but this didn't solve the problem either.

Any ideas what might be the problem here? I honestly run out of ideas. The code can be found [here](https://github.com/YvesDeutschmann/proposal-website) and the website is hosted [here](https://proposal-website.herokuapp.com/) Click on 'Analyze' and 'Show me more details' to get to the problematic page.

I appreciate every input. Thanks inadvance.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution. Even though I changed the file extensions from 'JPG' to 'jpg' locally this change didn't make it to GitHub. I ended up converting the files to PNG format, adding and referencing them in the code and they finally showed up after deployment.